# Rails 3 f.select set up for use in a search form using Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select

Apologies in advance for the total beginner question, but since I am a beginner here goes: In my Rails 3 app I have an attribute on my `Profile` model for `:subject`. In my form, I have the following code for the user to assign the `:subject`:

```
<%= f.select :profile_subject, options_for_select([['Select', 0], ['Arts', 1], ['Biology', 2], ['Business', 3], ['Chemistry', 4], ['English', 5], ['Foreign Language', 6], ['Government', 7], ['Health', 8], ['History', 9], ['Math', 10], ['Physics', 11], ['Vocational', 12]]) %>
```

I want to utilize the `:subject` strings for two things really:

1. To render in my view
2. To use in a search form (I'm using [Ransack](http://rubygems.org/gems/ransack) for the search)

I don't think I set this up in my database (or built the form) properly, as I only appear to be storing the id ("ex: 1") and not the string ("ex: Arts"). Before I remove the option id though, I'm curious: For something like this, is it considered good practice to include an option id as well as a string in the select? Or strip the id and just keep it as an array of strings only?

The reason for asking all this is regarding my search form. As I mentioned I'm using Ransack, and I'm just not sure how to make the `f.select` work with just a bunch of strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I hadn't set this up properly in my db. So I corrected the form so the :subject stored was a string. Here's the new form:

```
<%= f.select :subject, options_for_select([['Select', ''], ['Arts'], ['Biology'], ['Business'], ['Chemistry'], ['English'], ['Foreign Language'], ['Government'], ['Health'], ['History'], ['Math'], ['Physics'], ['Vocational']], :selected => @profile.subject) %>
```

Then for the search form I just had to add a predicate `_eq`:

```
<%= f.select :profile_subject_eq, options_for_select([['Select', ''], ['Arts'], ['Biology'], ['Business'], ['Chemistry'], ['English'], ['Foreign Language'], ['Government'], ['Health'], ['History'], ['Math'], ['Physics'], ['Vocational']], :selected => :profile_subject) %>
```

And now it works.

Comment: Travis, this just solved it for me. Glad to see you're still helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

I would store the array of subjects in the model for several reasons.  You can use it for validation.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  SUBJECT_VALUES = %w( Arts Biology Business Chemistry English Foreign\ Language Government Health History Math Physics Vocational )
  validates_inclusion_of :subject, :in => SUBJECT_VALUES
end
```

Your new/edit form can use that easily.

```
<%= f.select :subject, Profile::SUBJECT_VALUES %>
```

And your search form.

```
<%= f.select :profile_subject_eq, Profile::SUBJECT_VALUES %>
```

And if you want to allow multiple select for searching.

```
<%= f.collection_select :profile_subject_in, Profile::SUBJECT_VALUES, :to_s, :to_s, {}, { :multiple => true } %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out! One thing I'm having trouble with is when I select an option and the search form submits, the `subject` value returns to "Select", not the value shown. Do you know what might be happening there?

Comment: @tvalent2 Which one are you trying for the search form?  The "f.select :subject" is for new/edit.